# Ionic + AGM (Angular Google Maps) blank screen in fullscreen mode

Tags: angular, google-maps, google-chrome, ionic-framework, angular-google-maps

Actually, I cannot get what's wrong.
I know that finally this is CSS problem. The map is rendering, I can exit full screen mode by pressing escape, but when I'm entering full screen mode, I see only white overlay and my navbar above.

I have tried to remove all css except agm-map { height: 200px; }. But this doesn't help, so I think this problem is even in blank project.

I know that I can make my own, custom full screen mode, but I want to use the in-built feature.

webkit --

**-- EDIT:**

Map is not working on sub pages.
I am loading a primary page. If I will use the map on it - then it renders ok, but if I will use it in subpage, I will get the blank screen in full screen mode, here is the code, which shows you, how I load the subpages.

**App Component:**

```
<ion-nav [root]="rootPage" #nav></ion-nav>
```

here, `rootPage = 'Layout'`

**Layout Page:**

```
<app-menu [content]="nav" (tendersList)="onTendersList()"></app-menu>
<ion-header>
    <app-header (logoClicked)="onLoad('Tenders')"></app-header>
</ion-header>
<ion-content>
    <ion-nav [root]="rootPage"></ion-nav>
</ion-content>
```

here, `rootPage = 'TenderPage'` (the subpage)

**Tender Page:**

```
<ion-content>
  <agm-map [gestureHandling]="'cooperative'" [fullscreenControl]="true"></agm-map>
</ion-content>
```

In general, I am using subpages, because I want to share menu and header on some pages. (Not on all). My first login page should not have ment and the header, that's why I did not implement this in AppComponent (main, app-entryt, component).

**-- UPDATE:**

I've found the cause of the problem, it is because of ion-content is inside another ion-content, but I still have to find a solution to add 70px padding from the nav-bar (which is 70px height). If I use margin-top/top: 70px, then it cuts footer by 70px, but the header will be ok. If I use padding-top, then it does not affect anything, because all elements are have position: absolute.

Comment: In Ionic I put the topbar nav inside the <ion-content> to stop this

Comment: I think you can check this one. It's late but helpful might be https://medium.com/@gamiparesh5/agm-angular-google-map-in-ionic-4-bc97bcc9421f